# Android app launch logo changing to black & white

Tags: android, icons, android-launcher

I'm trying set the new logo for my Android app, but when I select the image, logo is turning into black & white. Could you help me understanding what's going wrong here? Attached is sample screen print.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you've accidentally selected foreground color

Comment: No, it's clear picture with white background

Comment: Then you could try converting your PNG file to JPG with PS and try creating the launcher icon. It could be a file issue after all

Comment: Very strange issue. A guess may be the way the image was saved? I have tested some of my icons with a transparent background and they are all coming out fine.

Comment: Yes, quite strange issue. I tried other images also Google icon itself but same, it's turning either completely black or black & white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution or issue causing this problem. I was using Android Studio Preview and that was the issue. Preview is not ready for production app, it's like beta version. I reverted to the stable version of the app and it's working perfectly for icons. Attached is sample image for Android Studio 2.1.2[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

Comment: Doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: And he'd better stick on AS provided tool. It's pretty much the same though

Comment: Yes, I'm using basic tool provided in android studio